# French equivalent of the figurative Japanese expression "風のおもむくままに / at the mercy of the wind"

Tags: expressions, japonais

In Japanese, we say "風のおもむくままに + (e.g. 旅をする)" to express the idea of e.g. travelling round the world ***without any predetermined plan*** as if you are letting yourself wander around ***at the mercy of the wind***.

> Je voyage **là où le vent m’emporte**.

This phrasing came to mind, but I'm having second thoughts about it, perhaps on account of the negative sense conveyed by a similar expression "Autant en emporte le vent".

How do French speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: Maybe "au gré du vent"?

Comment: This is it @Luke Sawczak, you should answer that

Comment: Maybe include a literal translation of the Japanese idiom (As the wind goes?) in the question, just as a bonus for the readers who don't speak the language.

Comment: @Eauquidort It's exactly as described in the title: "at the mercy of the wind". :D

Answer (score 4):

It seems that an idiomatic equivalent is surprisingly similar literally as well:

> Je voyage **au gré du vent**.

This also appears to exist in the plural and the two are [in close competition](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=au%20gr%C3%A9%20du%20vent%2Cau%20gr%C3%A9%20des%20vents&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cau%20gr%C3%A9%20du%20vent%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bau%20gr%C3%A9%20du%20vent%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAu%20gr%C3%A9%20du%20vent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cau%20gr%C3%A9%20des%20vents%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bau%20gr%C3%A9%20des%20vents%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAu%20gr%C3%A9%20des%20vents%3B%2Cc0).

[image: Why all the later dates are '32' I cannot say]

It seems that the wind suggests the same figurative expression in many languages — also compare English "where(ver) the wind blows".

Comment: Indeed, it's tempting to go for "au gré du vent". The thing is that I tend to associate the expression with its literal sense, that is, the wind moving objects physically, so I wasn't sure of its figurative aspect.

Answer (score 3):

- Je vais là où le vent me porte
- Je vais là où le vent me mène
- Je voyage au petit bonheur la chance